# Does the source of a code sample matter when tagging?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

I had noticed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462335/multiple-functions-with-javascript-promises) which includes a great code sample; The code sample the asker posted had nothing to do with React or redux though; the code seemed to me to be intimately involved with knowledge of mongoose.  Regardless, the question was tagged with reactjs, redux and react-redux.  I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11921652) to remove those tags and add the mongoose tag, however this edit was rejected by the asker basically stating that because the code sample came from a code base which serves as a sample for react and redux, his question was therefore worthy of the react and redux tags.

Is there anything wrong with my logic in suggesting that edit?  Is there any reason I could have been wrong to?

Comment: I don't know any of the languages in question. Do you think they wanted a Mongoose solution or one in one of the tags that they had attached? It seems like a low quality question/self-answer, in any case.

Comment: The question is basically "how do I wrap this mongoose query in a JavaScript Promise."  My opinion, based on the answer that was provided soon after my suggested edit, is that the answer required some small amount of knowledge of mongoose.  There isn't a hint of reactjs, redux or react-redux (all javascript libraries) in either the sample code nor any possible answer.  I suppose the tags would be alright if it was something like "how do I do this query in a redux reducer" or "how do I do this query when the react component is mounted"

Comment: I wonder if the edit would have been better received if you added the Mongoose tag without removing any other tags. **Is the code even useful for the other libraries in question?** Also, does the answer actually solve the problem?

Comment: Through logical reasoning, I believe the answer does solve the problem.  I don't believe the code is directly useful for the other libraries in question.  They can be used together in the same app of course, but that's about the only overlap.  Thanks for the tip though, adding the mongoose tag without removing other tags.